# Using Rally SDK 2.0p4: What should I do about 'Deprecated' warnings in the service responses?

Tags: rally

On the Rally dev site, the 2.X Apps SDK seems to be the latest. And that is what I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p4/sdk-debug.js" ></script>
```

I am using the data model stuff, from the SDK, i.e., Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel and Model.load

It works fine, but I notice the following message coming back inside the service responses:

> "Warnings": ["Start position 401 is past the end of results.", "API status is Deprecated and will become Not Supported on 10/26/2013"],

Why is it calling a deprecated version of the service?

More text from the response that might be helpful:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.callback32({"QueryResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "1", "_rallyAPIMinor": "37", "Errors": [], "Warnings":...
```

A sample request that the JavaScript SDK seems to be sending to the service:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.37/Defect.js?_dc=1379957135087&_method=GET&start=401&pagesize=200&order=FormattedId%20DESC%2CObjectID&query=(%20(%20(%20(%20(%20(%20(%20(%20(%20ScheduleState%20!%3D%20%22Accepted%22%20)%20AND%20(%20ScheduleState%20!%3D%20%22Released%22%20)%20)%20AND%20(%20ScheduleState%20!%3D%20%22Completed%22%20)%20)%20AND%20(%20State%20!%3D%20%22Duplicate%22%20)%20)%20AND%20(%20State%20!%3D%20%22Can%27t%20Reproduce%22%20)%20)%20AND%20(%20State%20!%3D%20%22Not%20a%20Bug%22%20)%20)%20AND%20(%20State%20!%3D%20%22Closed%22%20)%20)%20AND%20(%20State%20!%3D%20%22Fixed%22%20)%20)%20AND%20(%20Release%20!%3D%20%22%2Frelease%2F6468789462%22%20)%20)&fetch=FormattedId%2CName&includePermissions=true&project=%2Fproject%2F6266786459&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=true&jsonp=Ext.data.JsonP.callback32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest AppSDK 2 is AppSDK 2rc1. It is using the latest version of WS API v2.0.
However depending on the code more or less extensive refactoring may be needed to go from 2.0p4 to 2.0rc1. Charts in rc1 and collections in WS API v2.0 are examples where more expensive changes to the existing 2.0p4 or 2.0p5 code will be needed.

Having said that, I believe nothing will happen on 10/26/2013, and we will continue to answer customer questions and your apps and customization will continue to function.

Web Services API deprecation policy and last supported dates for each version of API are available [here](http://help.rallydev.com/web-services-api-deprecation-policy), but as long as you are not using SOAP the immediate effect is not significant, and in the immediate future the warning can be ignored. As of WSAPI 2.0 we are fully discontinuing support for SOAP and XML. It does not mean that existing SOAP custom code will be intentionally broken, but we strongly recommend not to write anything new using SOAP interface.

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. Sounds like I have nothing to worry about. I will experiment with upgrading to the latest, but if it's difficult to get working, I'll stick with 2.0p4. I also just figured out that I can add ?wsapiVersion=1.43 and that pushes out the 'no longer supported' date somewhat.

Comment: That's correct. The WS API deprecation policy and dates document linked in the answer shows that 1.43 will be "officially" supported til June 2014.

Comment: I tried out switching to 2rc1, and I am seeing some differences I don't understand. Just to see what you have to say, I am going to post a separate question about this.

Comment: By the way, I was looking at that page on last-supported dates, and the 2.x versions aren't listed. Just the 1.x. So I wonder how much time upgrading to web service 2.x will buy me.

Comment: v2.0 is the latest version. It is fully supported, and going to stay that way in the foreseeable future.